# reducing duplication of code in inheritance

Tags: java, if-statement, inheritance, bluej

The method reads the data for the First class and second Class using scanner and then it stores them in the ArrayList the tow class. First and Second are inherited From Main Class. The problem I have is the duplication I created to objects.

How can I only create one and use it for both.

```
import java.io.File;

import java.io.FileNotFoundException;

import java.util.*;

public class Auto {
    private ArrayList<Main> lists;

    public Auto() {
        lists = new ArrayList<Main>();
    }

    public void storeData(Main main) {
        list.add(main);
    }

    public void readFile(String filePath) throws FileNotFoundException {

        File file = new File(filePath);
        Scanner input = new Scanner(file);
        String dataToBe;
        while (input.hasNext()) {
            String lines = input.nextLine().trim();
            Scanner scanner = new Scanner(lines).useDelimiter("\n[ ]*,");
            if (lines.startsWith("Data")) {
                if (lines.startsWith("FirstData")) {
                    dataToBe = "first";
                } else if (lines.startsWith("SecondData")) {
                    dataToBe = "second";
                }

            } else if (dataToBe.equals("first")) {
                Main main = new First();
                main.readData(scanner);
                storeData(main);

            } else if (dataToBe.equals("second")) {
                Main main = new Second();
                main.readData(scanner);
                storeData(main);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This won't work. `lines` cannot start with `"Data"` and `"FirstData"` at the same time.

Comment: Can you make your question more specific? What would you like to save in single class? Can you move this data properties to main class, and create its instances insted First and Second?

Comment: I am reading from a text File and it works fine and its stored in the arryList

Comment: Which duplication you are talking about? Whst is duplicated, what are you eant to re- use?

Answer (score 1):

#### Okay, you might think its longwinded, but it's probably how I would do it under your restrictions.

```
public void readFile(String filePath) throws FileNotFoundException {

    final Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\n[ ]*,");
    final Scanner fileInput = new Scanner(new File(filePath));

    while (fileInput.hasNextLine()) {
        final String line = fileInput.nextLine().trim();
        final Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(line);
        final StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        
        byte flag = 0;
        while (matcher.find()) {
            final String match = matcher.group();
            if(match.startsWith("FirstData")){ flag = 1;}
            else if(match.startsWith("SecondData")){flag = 2;}
            builder.append(line).append(",");
        }
        
        Main mainObj = (flag == 1) ? (new First()) : (flag == 2) ? (new Second()) : null;
        if(null != mainObj){
            mainObj.readData(builder.toString());
        }
    }
}
```

The approach above does require you to accept a String instead of a Scanner in the parameter, but the CSV format passed to each method lets the behaviour of each class handle the work.